# Undefined offset:1, 2 3 etc

Tags: php, sql, arrays

As title explains I get the error :

```
Undefined offset: 1,2,3 in <file> on line ...
```

Not offset 0?

```
$csv_file = $filename; 
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {
    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
    $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
    $insert_csv = array();
    $insert_csv['Point_number'] = $csv_array[0];
    $insert_csv['Easting'] = $csv_array[1];
    $insert_csv['Northing'] = $csv_array[2];
    $insert_csv['Reduced_level'] = $csv_array[3];
    $query = "INSERT INTO export(point_number,easting,northing,reduced_level)
    VALUES('".$insert_csv['Point_number']."','".$insert_csv['Easting']."','".$insert_csv['Northing']."','".$insert_csv['Reduced_level']."')";
    $n=mysql_query($query, $connect );
    $i++;
}
fclose($csvfile);
```

Comment: your code is trying to flee to the right

Comment: Seems as if the file contains lines without a comma

Comment: ...or it's failing to open a line. The error is pretty self explanatory, do some debugging.

Comment: thanks luke, works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$csv_array[1];`, `$csv_array[2];` and `$csv_array[3];` don't exists inside your `$csv_array`. As suggested, do a `var_dump($csv_array)` below `$csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);` and see what is in there!